# SQL Server stored procedure error: "Error Message: Must declare the scalar variable" referencing a variable with sp_executesql but not without

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

When I want to add datetime column to entire table I can write a stored procedure which takes a date as input and then stores it into the table - like so:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[set_datettime]
     (@importDate VARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[table1] 
    SET uploadDate = @importDate
END
```

But when I want to make the table dynamic I need to use `sp_executesql`. So my thought is I can do this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[set_datettime]
     (@tableName VARCHAR(100), @importDate VARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @Sql = 'UPDATE dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) + ' SET uploadDate = @importDate';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
END
```

but now I get an error:

> Error Message: Must declare the scalar variable @importDate

Despite clearly declaring the variable. Even if I try to explicitly declare the variable again I get the error that I cant declare duplicate variables.

Other thing which I tried was to do:

```
SET @Sql = 'UPDATE dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) + ' SET uploadDate = ' + @importDate;
```

But this throws an error

> Invalid column name 10-10-2019

Lastly I was able to accomplish the task (somewhat) by changing to

```
    SET @Sql = 'UPDATE dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) + ' SET uploadDate = GETDATE()';
```

But in this solution I define the date in the stored procedure and doesn't take it as input, which is not ideal.

How can I have dynamic table definition while still keeping the date input variable dynamic also?

Comment: You have to concatenate the parameter into the SQL string.

Comment: as in: " SET @Sql = 'UPDATE dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) + concat(' SET uploadDate = ', @importDate);
" that gives me syntax error

Comment: Also: if it's a date - then ***WHY?!?!?*** are you using `VARCHAR(100)` as the parameter type?? First of all - 100 chars is way too long for a date - and more importantly: you should always use the **most appropriate** data type - which would be `DATE` (or `DATETIME2(n)` if you need the time portion as well) - but certainly not `VARCHAR(n)`

Comment: Well, yeah, except you need to use correct syntax. A string literal must have single quotes on both ends, then you can use the plus sign to concatenate in your variable. However, it is a bit dangerous as this leaves you potentially vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.

Comment: No, @theMayer, you don't. That just creates security holes.

Comment: @Larnu, I find that programming without knowing what you are doing is generally what creates security holes. This is merely one method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parametrise your dynamic statement. I'm typing on my phone right now, so I apologise for any typographical errors:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@importdate date', @importdate;
```

Never inject parameters in your dynamic statements. It creates huge security flaws in your SQL, called SQL Injection.

Edit: not on my phone now, so can write out the complete SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[set_datettime]
     (@tableName sysname, @importDate date)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @Sql = 'UPDATE dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) + ' SET uploadDate = @importDate;';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql, N'@importDate date', @importDate;
END;
```

Comment: I'm **not sure** but @importdate might need to be converted to date since it's declared as varchar(100).  `EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@importdate date', convert(date,@importdate);`  Otherwise this answer is the non-sql-injection way to do this.

Comment: You won't be able to do that @avery_larry, you can't pass an express as a parameter. The OP should be using the correct datatype to start with (as marc_s says in the comments).

Comment: How would the @SQL statement look in this case? I'm not 100% following here.

Comment: I've updated it for you, @Anton, as I'm back at my PC now.

Comment: It would also be great to hear from whimever the downvote was for. If you feel that this answer can be improved, or is dangerous, share that reason. I would say I consider myself an handling expert on Dynamic SQL. If you *do* feel you know how to improve this further, please share so that I can learn something more from it and then help the community more in the future when I continue to publish articles on the subject.

Comment: @Anton Check out the documentation for sp_executesql.  In general, the `N'@parameter datatype` is how you declare a parameter with sp_executesql.  Then you pass a parameter into the `@Sql` portion.  Thus, when sp_executesql is executed, the part of `@Sql` that shows `SET uploadDate = @importDate;'` will actually use `@importDate` as a parameter instead of a literal string.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thank you for the answer & explanation

Answer (score -1):

Test it first:

```
declare @tableName varchar(100) = 'sometable'
, @importDate varchar(100) = '10-10-2019'

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @Sql = 'UPDATE dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) + ' SET uploadDate = ' + @importDate

select @Sql
```

This give you an incorrect statement:

```
UPDATE dbo.[sometable] SET uploadDate = 10-10-2019
```

Try this:

```
SET @Sql = 'UPDATE dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) + ' SET uploadDate = ' + '''' + @importDate + ''''
```

Which gives you

```
UPDATE dbo.[sometable] SET uploadDate = '10-10-2019'
```

Comment: thanks that works, but idk why? does the quote spam convert it to string?

Comment: What do you mean why? Setting a date without quotes (uploadDate = 10-10-2019) is not valid syntax, 10-10-2019 is a calculation resulting in negative 2019, it needs the quotes.  Also, why pass dates in as varchar, why not pass them is as dates?

Comment: Don't inject the value... **Parametrise** it. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql

Comment: @larnu.  I'm aware.  I simply fixed Antons existing method, I did not say it was the correct way to achieve what he wants.  My answer is valid.  If you have a better valid answer then please post it as an answer and let people judge it.

Comment: You didn't "fix" it though, you created a security flaw. It's worse than it was now.

Comment: @GandRalph It's even worse if you know it's vulnerable to sql injection and post it anyway -- and completely without warnings or alternate recommendations.

Comment: I really hope that the downvote on my answer is not a "revenge" downvote from yourself @GandRalph. If it is from you, I would be most greatful to hear your opinions on how i can improve it, as I am always looking for ways to improve my published articles on SSC on the subject of dynamic SQL. Of course, if it isn't yourself, you can at least see how you would parametrise the statements in the future, and i hope you too learn something so that you can keep your code secure in the future.